# Limiting Children of Object in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I am looking to get back my whole object, but limit one of my children objects.

For example, say you take a chat app like firebase does and you do "rooms".

So you might have

```
rooms: {
    mainroom:{
         name: something,
         otherAttrs: mfasfd,
         messages: {
             0: {
                 message: something
              },
             1: {
                 message: something else
             }
         }
    }
```

I may have 300 messages in that mainroom, but I want to limit it to 30 say.  This example is basic, but in my actual application my objects are very related so I don't want to denormalize any further.

I could do a mainroom call, and then do another child call off of that, but I am wondering if I would get dinged twice.  in the initial call it would load all messages anyways, and then I would load 30 of them with the child call.  Was just hoping someone would have a better recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by reading up about [denormalization](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html). This is a concept which is enforced in SQL by table structures, but also important in NoSQL, although you're given enough rope to tangle yourself up and have a bad day.

So the first step is to split messages into its own path:

```
URL/rooms
URL/messages
```

Now you can grab your meta data and messages separately, and call limit to set the number loaded:

```
var fbRef = new Firebase(URL);
var roomRef = fbRef.child('rooms/'+roomId);
var chatRef = fbRef.child('messages/'+roomId).limit(30);
```

In case you're not convinced that these should be split up, you're going to run into this same issue when you want to create a dropdown containing a list of room names (you have to load all your messages in the current data structure, just to get the room names).

For great justice, split meta data and detailed records into their own paths. Otherwise, all your base are belong to bandwidth.